# Has a user seen a certain tweet? Twitter API

Tags: c#, twitter, tweets, tweetsharp

I have a use case where I need to check if a user has somehow scrolled past, or seen a tweet in their twitter feed. I am not talking about likes or retweets because that obviously builds a connection between the tweet and the user via an action.

I am trying to find out some way to even get an educated guess that the user might or might not have seen a certain tweet when using twitter.

I am working with TweetSharp and C# but even if it's possible via some third party, any clue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, but that data simply isn't recorded in the API.

If your user is using an app that you've built, then you can track which tweets have been requested.  But, just because a tweet has been downloaded, it doesn't mean it has been seen.